# Running background processes in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Can we run following tasks in the back ground in a iPhone application:

```
√ Camera --> Take photo (timer = infinity) (keep on taking photos) 
√ Video
√ Backlight --> On for certain duration (Customizable)
√ Flickering --> 5secs (Customizable)
√ Vibration (Background)
√ Voice Call --> Long call or multiple calls (Call duration/Time b/w calls/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Camera - no
- Video - no
- Backlight - no
- Flickering - don't know what this means
- Vibration - could be triggered with Push
- Voice Call - yes, VOIP is allowed

Answer (score 2):

No iOS multitasking is very restrictive in what you can do.

You could do a voip service in the background, but you won't have access to backlight, camera, vibration motor etc.

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html#multitasking)